# Gradle Plugin to generate cucumber report not compiling

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am writing Cucumber Automated Test Cases in java, using REST Assured.

All the tests run as JUnit tests, & as Gradle tests, & they all pass successfully.

The next step I need to take is to generate a *Cucumber Report* based on these test results.

I've been told that I need to find a *gradle plugin for cucumber*.

So far, I've tried putting the following code (from here: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.spacialcircumstances.gradle-cucumber-reporting) into my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
  id "com.github.spacialcircumstances.gradle-cucumber-reporting" version "0.0.12"
}
```

But, when I try to refresh the gradle, I get this error:

> Sychrnoize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an error in the referenced Gradle build.

Is this the correct plugin to generate this cucumber report, and if so, why is it not being accepted by the gradle?